# Is it Possible to Disable PyDev Parameter Code Completion?

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I am using the PyDev add-on for Eclipse, and most of the autocomplete features are helpful, but I would rather not have all of the parameters filled in for functions, especially when some of the arguments are optional. I could not find any way to disable this in preferences without disabling code completion altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You can leave Ctrl pressed when you apply the completion (this will leave both the parameters and the parenthesis out -- and will also override the next word).

Comment: Thank you, I will start using that to avoid this situation when necessary in the future.

Comment: +1 That is a nice feature I did not know of but helps a lot espacially if dealing with long signatures.

Comment: Yup it was annoying to see it fill out all the optional arguments. I wonder why ctrl+enter is not the default. Added to the list of changes I make to default PyDev (I also turn off almost all of automatic insertion of matching pairs,... because it screws with my mental model during typing)

Comment: Now I try to use ctrl+Enter, but it sometimes deleted the next line too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible in PyDev/Eclipse to have function code completion that does not fill in the parameters.

However, I'm not sure why you would want it disabled because Eclipse allows you to **TAB** through parameter arguments.  **Typing out the entire function** will also not generate the parameters.

Lastly, remember that you can always do **Ctrl+Delete** and **Ctrl+Backspace** to rapidly delete extra parameters.